# Re write rule refuses to function pagination

Tags: php, mod-rewrite

I am trying to get my url for my pagination to display as follows

example.com/members/p1

as of now it shows

example.com/members.php?page=1

I have tried the re write below. don't from fr write generator but it does not work

`.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^p/([^/]*)$ members.php?page=$1 [L]
```

PHP:

```
<?php        
   $number_list = array();        
    for ($i = 1; $i <= $count; $i ++) {

      if ($i == $page) {

         echo "<li><a class='active' href='members.php?page={$i}'>{$i}</a></li>";

            } else {

         echo "<li><a href='members.php?page={$i}'>{$i}</a></li>";
      }
   }        
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to separate between the code you output to the user (using PHP) and mod_rewrite (which translate the pretty-URLs you have to the actual URLs with the variables your PHP code handles).

Lets say you want to write a link to `example.com/members/p1`. Your php code should look like this:

```
$i = 1;
echo "<li><a href='members/p{$i}'>{$i}</a></li>";
```

Now - when someone enter the page `members/p1` - you want your PHP code to think that this someone actually entered `users.php?page=1` (it's much easier because this way you have the variable `$_GET['page']` you can use.

So, to sum it up:
1. In your PHP code - you generate "pretty" links.
2. In your `.htaccess` file you tell the server to "think" that when it gets a request to `^members/([^/][0-9]*)$` it should treat it as `users.php?page=$1`

Comment: @Dekei Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error.

Comment: Change the rewrite rule to `RewriteRule ^members/([^/][0-9]*)$ users.php?page=$1 [L]`

Comment: I added as you stated and it took my whole site down

Comment: Can you update the question with the exact code you have in your `.htaccess` ?

Comment: @Dekei I moved my page out of members and my code and updated

Comment: You have a typo there `ewriteRule`. Is it the same in your `.htaccess` file?

Comment: @Dekei whats up there now is in my rewrite the r was missing from copy